# What command shows the architecture of a binary file on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, architecture

I used it a while ago, but cannot find now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably want the [`file`](https://manpage.me/?q=file) command.

Answer (score 11):

Use the built-in [`file`](https://manpage.me/?q=file) command.

For example:

```sh
file -b pydevd_cython.cpython-310-darwin.so`
```

Note: the `-b` or `--brief` option prevents the output from echoing the file-name again, only shows the *file-type* and *architecture* as `arm64` (for the new Apple Silicon chip M1):

```
Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
```

See also: [How to Determine File Type & Encoding from Command Line in Mac OS X](https://osxdaily.com/2015/08/11/determine-file-type-encoding-command-line-mac-os-x/).

#### Alternative

To output just the architecture you can also use the command [`lipo -archs`](https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html) like

```sh
lipo -archs /System/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
```

It will list the used architectures, e.g.

```
x86_64 arm64
```

See also:

- Ask Different: [How can I distinguish ARM binaries from x86 binaries on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429197/how-can-i-distinguish-arm-binaries-from-x86-binaries-on-macos)
- [Magic, lipo and testing for Universal binaries – The Eclectic Light Company](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/07/24/magic-lipo-and-testing-for-universal-binaries/)